# HttpListenerRequest.HasEntityBody is False value for unknown reason

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, httplistenerrequest

I've being trying to implement OAuth 2.0 with google on a web application.
But for some reason, `Request.HasEntityBody` property is `null`.

On the Oauth server, I get the response with Status Code `200` with the valid data but no progress on login phase.

Steps I'm doing are:

1. booting app
2. login with google.
3. browser tab opens with https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth.
4. login closes tab and open the app on login menu instead of logging in.

Any tips on how to solve this case?
Thanks in advance.

```
public async Task<int> ListenCallback(string requestURL, string defaultBrowserName)
{
    int statusCode = 0;

    try
    {
        HttpListenerContext ctx = await listener.GetContextAsync();
        // ctx.Request.HasEntityBody = Null

        HttpListenerRequest req = ctx.Request;
        HttpListenerResponse resp = ctx.Response;

        resp.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
        resp.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        resp.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        resp.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.ContentType = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";

        string jsonString = new StreamReader(req.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString))
        {
            statusCode = WriteResponseToCache(jsonString: jsonString, responseURL: requestURL, isRefresh: false);
        }

        resp.Close();
        listener.Close();
        CloseOauthTab(defaultBrowserName);

        return statusCode;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        listener.Stop();
        listener.Close();
        CloseOauthTab(defaultBrowserName);
        
        if (!IsFailover)
        {
            if ((ex is TimeoutException) ||
               ((ex is WebException) &&
                (ex as WebException).Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout))
            {
                IsFailover = true;
                return await OauthLoginRequest();
            }
        }

            return statusCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: You posting doesn't make a lot of sense. The listener is at  the server and gets a request and then sends a response.  The response would contain the 200 OK.  the body of the request gets added at the client.  So if body is empty than client didn't send any data in the body.  OAUTH is probably working since you received the request.

Comment: need more detail and clarity